# Cannot update Jupyter to the latest version on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, python, jupyter

I use Jupyter notebooks with Python 3.5 and Python 2.7. However, I cannot update Jupyter:

```
vladimir@vladimir-ubuntu:~$ jupyter --version
4.2.0
```

But `pip3 freeze` gives me the following

```
vladimir@vladimir-ubuntu:~$ pip3 freeze
ipykernel==4.6.1
ipython==6.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.1
jupyter-console==5.1.0
jupyter-contrib-core==0.3.0
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.2.6
jupyter-core==4.3.0
jupyter-highlight-selected-word==0.0.11
jupyter-latex-envs==1.3.8.4
```

Note that both jupyter and ipython seems to be updated.

I also thought that Ubuntu runs `$jupyter` from python2.7 and I updated it as well. So, I had updated `jupyter` for both Pythons (even though the new version of `iPython` and `Jupyter` should not work on python2.7) but it does not solve the problem.

---

*UPD*: the About Jupyter looks like this: [About Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oYp5.png)

*UPD2*: I use pip (not conda).

*UPD3*: `[sudo] pip3 install jupyter` as well as `[sudo] pip install jupyter` give me a list of 'Requirement already satisfied'.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Anaconda? 
If so, try the following command and send us back the result:

```
conda update jupyter
```

Also check the following command as well (if necessary):

```
pip install -U jupyter
```

Comment: I use `pip`, not `conda` (updated). `pip install -U jupyter`gives me a list of `Requirement already satisfied`.

Comment: Just want to clarify, Are you talking about the Jupyter or about the Kernel?

Comment: I don't really follow what you are talking about. Both, I don't know...